# Setting owner ACL on Google Cloud Storage from Google App Engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When I create objects in Google Cloud Storage from a PHP Google App Engine instance, the ACL for owner doesn't get set, making it impossible to change things like cache control headers later on.

```
$options = ['gs' => ['acl' => 'public-read', 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain']];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents('gs://my_bucket/file.yadda');
```

How would I set a more detailed ACL setting, from PHP app engine, instead of using one of the predefined cloud storage ACL magic settings (public-read, owner-full-read-write, etc....)?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use the setup on default ACL for a bucket to make the default ACL on the bucket be what you want. At that point, anything created without an ACL declared will go to your default.

You don't even need to run anything in PHP to get that done. You just use your same code as now, don't specify an ACL, and you use gsutil to customize the default ACL with commands like :

```
gsutil defacl ch -u my-email@gmail.com:OWNER gs://«my_bucket»
```

More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#changingdefaultobject)

Comment: Thanks Patrice, I've tried that already.  The default ACL for the bucket does not pass ownership onto the bucket objects.  The objects created via PHP essentially have no OWNER.

Comment: @Tyguy7 Then maybe editing this in your question, along with the code you ran with that example, would make your question more complete? Because with the way your question read, if you tell me you setup a default ACL, I'll say you're not using it because your code sample assigns an ACL (I assume when you tested the default ACL you didn't use the same sample, but anyway). In general though, Can you edit in your question how you changed the default ACL on your bucket, and how you inserted THAT way?